# Multithread proxy checker not working as well

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, proxy

I'll show you a code that IS working, have no errors! But, the multithreading system isn't working as wells, the threads seem to be waiting for one to complete before initializing the next, like one-by-one. How can I solve this issue?

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
Dim proxies As New List(Of String)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim threads As Integer = NumericUpDown1.Value
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(threads, threads)
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads((threads / 2), (threads / 2))
    For Each proxy In proxies
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf check)
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub check()
    Dim myProxy As WebProxy
    For Each proxy As String In proxies
        Try
            myProxy = New WebProxy(proxy)
            Dim r As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/")
            r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36"
            r.Timeout = 3000
            r.Proxy = myProxy
            Dim re As HttpWebResponse = r.GetResponse()
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Working Proxy: " & proxy)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Unresponsive Proxy: " & proxy)
        End Try
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim fo As New OpenFileDialog
    fo.RestoreDirectory = True
    fo.Multiselect = False
    fo.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    fo.FilterIndex = 1
    fo.ShowDialog()
    If (Not fo.FileName = Nothing) Then
        Using sr As New StreamReader(fo.FileName)
            While sr.Peek <> -1
                proxies.Add(sr.ReadLine())
            End While
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
End class
```

P.S.: Public code

Comment: Please replace `While sr.Peek <> -1` with `While Not sr.EndOfStream`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.endofstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still not working... :(

Comment: Oh, I didn't say that would fix your problem. I was just pointing out that checking for `EndOfStream` is a much more clear way to, well   ... check for end of stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least part of the problem is that your `Button1` handler is creating a thread for each proxy, and the `check` method then iterates over the entire proxy list. That is, you have in your `Button1` handler:

```
For Each proxy In proxies
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf check)
Next
```

And in your `check` method:

```
For Each proxy As String In proxies
    Try
      ` other code here
    Catch
      ...
    End Try
Next
```

So every proxy gets checked by every thread.

You need to make your `check` method take a parameter: the string it's supposed to check. So it looks like this:

```
Public Sub check(stateInfo as Object)
    Dim proxyString as String = CType(stateInfo, String)
    Dim myProxy As WebProxy
    Try
        myProxy = New WebProxy(proxyString)
        Dim r As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/")
        r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36"
        r.Timeout = 3000
        r.Proxy = myProxy
        Dim re As HttpWebResponse = r.GetResponse()
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Working Proxy: " & proxyString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Unresponsive Proxy: " & proxyString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And in your `Button1` handler:

```
For Each proxy In proxies
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf check, proxy)
Next
```

Also, I strongly suggest that you *not* disable the check for illegal cross-thread calls. That's going to bite you one of these days. Use synchronization for those calls.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing reply! But, "proxy is not declared" on your new check function, so, what should I do?

Comment: @Giuseppe: my error. I changed it to `proxyString`. See my updated code.